# Button with image and not visible text properties

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

Can I create a button with both .Image and .Text properties simultaniously, in such way, that text is not visible on form, and is created just for identifying what button should do at the moment?

Using TextAlign and TextImageRelation properties doesn't help. Text is always visible, just a position changes.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Button bRenameCourse;

this.bRenameCourse.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace;

this.bRenameCourse.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("bRenameCourse.Image")));
this.bRenameCourse.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(966, 6);
this.bRenameCourse.Name = "bRenameCourse";
```

I want this text "Rename" to be not visible on button

```
this.bRenameCourse.Text = "Rename";
this.bRenameCourse.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(64, 60);
this.bRenameCourse.TabIndex = 10;
this.bRenameCourse.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
this.bRenameCourse.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.bRenameCourse_Click);
```

Here is why do I want it works :

```
private void bRenameCourse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bRenameCourse.Text.Equals("Rename"))
    {
        //DO SMTHNG
        bRenameCourse.Text = "OK";
    }
    else if (bRenameCourse.Text.Equals("OK"))
    {
        //DO SMTHNG
        bRenameCourse.Text = "Rename";
    }
}
```

I can avoid this using some flags, but I'd like to know if it's possible in general.

Comment: One of the possible solutions is using .Image.Tag . But i thing it's not a good practice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `.Text` property of the button to store information.You can use the `.Tag` property

ie

```
  this.bRenameCourse.Tag  = "Rename";
```

And in the Event

```
private void bRenameCourse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bRenameCourse.Tag.Equals("Rename"))
    {
        //DO SMTHNG
        bRenameCourse.Tag = "OK";
    }
    else if (bRenameCourse.Tag.Equals("OK"))
    {
        //DO SMTHNG
        bRenameCourse.Tag = "Rename";
    }
}
```

Just set the `.Text` property to `""`(blank or empty)

Comment: Great! I found .Image.Tag property, but didn't see just a Tag for button :) Thank you.